# Export data from non-relational database from 2003 to a new relational database for an ASP.NET MVC 5 app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, asp.net-mvc, database

We have a really old non-relational database (SQL Server) and ASP.NET app from 2003 with a bunch of data.

We want to export this data and import it into a new relational database based on ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework. What is the best approach for this?

We're thinking an XML solution where we first export the data from the old database, create an XML-document, we add the data to this XML-document, parse the document and then use the XML-document as a source for importing the data into the new database. It is also worth mentioning that the old database will continue to be operational and will get updated with new table rows once or twice a day. These new rows will have to be exported and imported into the new database through a scheduled task in Windows.

Are there any other (better) alternatives for continuously exporting and importing the data daily?

Another solution would be to directly export and import the data between the databases without using an XML-document in between.

The third option I can think of is creating an API for the old database that the new database can talk to through the MVC 5 app.

What is the preferred alternative here?

Comment: SQL Server has SQL Server Integration Services [edit: mixed up my component names] which, as an ETL tool, is designed to copy, transform and move data. Why not use that?

Comment: we have to continuously export and import the data using a windows schedular task. Can you do that with those tools?

Comment: what's an "ASP.NET MVC 5 relational database"?

Comment: judging from your tags im pretty sure you know what i meant.

Comment: No we don't, "ASP.NET 5" is not a database, nor is a web app written with it. But such an application probably uses a database. But for converting data into its database its other clients are almost certainly irrelevant unless (for some strange reason) you want an ASP.NET MVC web app to do the transfer (probably the wrong approach). TL;DR: focus on the databases, there structures and what needs to happen to the data.

Comment: ^^ what he said... @PussInBoots don't judge from my tags, instead make your question clearer.

Comment: clearer? updated the question.

Comment: For your third option (_"creating an API for the old database that the new database can talk to through the MVC 5 app"_), have you considered implementing a scheduled web callback system? This solution would use your current MVC application to do the work (that is, connect to both databases & transfer/transform the data). Take a look at [Revalee](https://revalee.sageanalytic.com/) to schedule a regularly occurring callback to your MVC app. [ Disclaimer: I was involved with this free, open source project; source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee). ]